# Deleting everything before and after matches

Tags: regex, perl

I've searched and searched but nothing works exactly as I need it to.

My script is doing everything correctly so far; inputs text file, which is one long line of characters. The script asks the user for a first input then a second input. I'm trying to get the script to remove all characters that come before the first input and after the second input. I DON'T want to delete the matching input itself.

e.g. If the file contained "1111111111111111111111111CAT1111DOG11111111111", and the user typed "CAT" for the first input and "DOG" for the second input, I want to finish with "CAT1111DOG".

I don't need help with inputs and exports etc. It's just working with my `$line` string. How can I delete everything before the first input variable and after the second input variable, but without removing those matches themselves? A regex solution perhaps? The input variables to be found in the file might not always be the same length by the way.

Comment: The goal is not to delete but to extract.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there must be a reason my searches weren't helping much. So my question has the opposite problem now, extracting between BUT INCLUDING the two patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This give what you expect.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @data = <DATA>;
print "Enter ther first value: ";
chomp (my $first =<>) ;
print "Enter the second value: ";
chomp (my $sec = <>);
my @ar =map{m/$first.*$sec/gi} @data; #simply do it
print "@ar\n";
__DATA__
1111111111111111111111111CAT1111DOG11111111111
```

I used the `map` function for match the data to begining and last. `.` this matches anything expect newline then `*` matches zero or more occurrence.

Comment: This works so far, though I want it to get the data from a file rather than type out the data each time I run it. It can be thousands of characters long.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
$one = $ARGV[0] || "CAT" ;
$two = $ARGV[1] || "DOG" ;
$str = $ARGV[2] || '1111111111111111111111111CAT1111DOG11111111111';

$abc;

# This version will capture the match to a new variable
if ($str =~ m/($one.*$two)/) {
  print "$1\n";
  $abc = $1;
}

# This version will replace the original string with the match
$str =~ s/.*($one.*$two).*/$1/;
print "$abc\n$str\n";
```

If you save the file, you can enter positional parameters as the user input.

Comment: For your second code, you don't need to put `.*` at the begining and at the end.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte True - amended

Comment: Note that the first example will find the *last* occurrence of `CAT`, while the second example will find the *first* occurrence. However, there may be only one occurrence, and the OP hasn't said what to do in the case of multiple matches.

Comment: It's actually a complicated string the user inputs, so there's no chance of finding more than one match of each.

Comment: For some reason the if statement isn't finding it. I can print the two inputs from the user and the original string before the IF statement and it's all fine, but nothing is printed in your example. It's like it doesn't find it. Using the second example btw.

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks for fixing, trying to do too many things at once

Comment: @user2906976 What are you actually entering? Are you sure you've got the regex correct?

Comment: Trying the first one now. For example:
while (my $line = <>){
    $line =~ s/.*($primer1.*$primer2).*/$1/;
    print "$line\n";
    push my @clone, "$line";
    print "@clone\n";
}

This prints, but it prints the original string. No changes, nothing extracted. I appreciate the help guys.

Comment: Ah, that's not exactly useful.

Comment: No matter, I can read it. If it's printing the original string, it's because the substitution has failed. You may want to even wrap that bit in an `if` statement. Also, if you use `my @clone`, won't you get a new array every time? You should initialise it outside the loop and just `push @clone ...`

Comment: The extra "my" was a mistake. It's been initialised outside the loop. I don't see why it's failing. To test this I've made a test file which is exactly like the example I suggessted 111111CAT111DOG1111. $primer1 is "CAT" and $primer2 is "DOG". Well, they're inputs but if I add prints for them they work perfectly before and after the regex stuff. It seems everything's fine but the substitution fails but I see no reason for it to.

Comment: It does seem to print because there is a newline. It's just $1 is empty.

Comment: Print the line before the substitution to make sure it's what you expect. Might also be worth stripping newlines from the string with `while (chomp(my $line = <>))`